# Odd covering system without modulus 3 (mod3)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, covering

The existence of odd covering system with distinct moduli is a famous open question proposed by [Erdős and Selfridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system#Systems_of_odd_moduli).

I wonder whether a restricted condition for the problem that odd covering system without modulus 3 is also an open problem. That is to say, whether an incongruent covering system with the minimum modulus greater than 3 and whose moduli are odd exist or not.

Thanks.

p.s. The same question was posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394827/odd-covering-system-without-modulus-3-pmod3). If I get an answer from one site I would delete the other.

Comment: This is weaker than what you're asking, but Hough and Neilsen have proved that in an odd covering system at least one modulus must be divisible by 3. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02133.pdf)

Comment: I suspect that your question is still an open problem.

Comment: @ThomasBloom : Thanks. It helped me a lot.

Comment: I note that OP has deleted the math.se post.